# SwiftUI: Computed Property from reusable View not working

Tags: swiftui, view, reusability, computed-properties

Using the SwiftUI framework, I created this reusable View (minus styling bells and whistles):

```
struct RatingView: View {
    let criteria: String
    @State var rating: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                if rating > 0 {
                    rating -= 1
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "heart.slash.fill")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("\(criteria): \(rating)")

            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                if rating < 1 {
                    rating += 1
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And implemented it here (again, without the styling bells and whistles):

```
struct ScoringView: View {
    let story = "Story"
    let cheese = "Cheese"
    let love = "Romance"
    let actor = "In character"
    
    var storyRating = 0
    var cheesyRating = 0
    var loveRating = 0
    var actorRating = 0
    
    var roundScore: Int {
        storyRating + cheesyRating + loveRating + actorRating
    }
    
    var body: some View {                 
        VStack {
            RatingView(criteria: story, rating: storyRating)
            RatingView(criteria: cheese, rating: cheesyRating)
            RatingView(criteria: love, rating: loveRating)
            RatingView(criteria: actor, rating: actorRating)
        }
                
        Spacer()
                
        VStack {
            Text("Score this round:")
            Text("\(roundScore)")
        }
    }
}
```

No matter the changes I make to the rating buttons, the `roundScore` computed property does not change and remains at zero.

I tested the computed property in a Playground, and it works! But since I wasn't able to find anything on SO about the combo of computed properties and reusable views, so I wonder if the reusable view is messing with me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something yo trigger `View` updates or SwiftUI doesn't know when to  redraw.

Add `@State`

```
@State var storyRating = 0
@State var cheesyRating = 0
@State var loveRating = 0
@State var actorRating = 0
```

and remove it from `RatingView`

```
@Binding var rating: Int
```

`@State` is a source of truth and `@Binding` is a two-way connection.

You will also have to add `$` when initializing views

```
RatingView(criteria: story, rating: $storyRating)
RatingView(criteria: cheese, rating: $cheesyRating)
RatingView(criteria: love, rating: $loveRating)
RatingView(criteria: actor, rating: $actorRating)
```

Comment: Awesome. It worked!

I just finished an iOS bootcamp, and this is my second solo project. I know I'll get to where you are someday, but I just love how simple you made that fix!

Should I update the question to clarify that it was about Binding vs. State?

Comment: I now have this issue with the RatingView_Preview: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Binding<Int>'. I can comment out the preview because I don't really need it, but it would be nice to figure this out. I tried creating a new property in the preview, but that doesn't work. I'll keep hammering this to get where you are!

Comment: Got the RatingView_Preview to work with the static func constant(_ value: Value) -> Binding<Value>, like this: RatingView(criteria: "Cheesiness?", rating: .constant(1))

Comment: @ScottyA The .constant(1) is correct for preview. That is its primary purpose